# Не работает команда в кроне

Tags: bash, shell, sh

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/mysqldump -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD > /sqldumps/"$(/bin/date +'%d_%m_%Y:%H')".sql
```

Не понимаю, что именно не работает в этом куске
Потестил команду date в командной строке, вроде все работает как надо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ man 5 crontab
...
Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless escaped with backslash (\),
will be changed into newline characters
...
```

вольный перевод:

> знаки процента (<kbd>%</kbd>) в команде, если перед ними не стоят обратные слэши (<kbd>\</kbd>), будут преобразованы в символы новой строки.

---

т.е., чтобы сохранить «нормальное» поведение, надо перед каждым символом <kbd>%</kbd> поставить обратный слэш <kbd>\</kbd>.